# Sending WM_SETTINGSCHANGE broadcast doesn't updates Environment Variables

Tags: c++, path, registry

I wrote a simple C++ program that edits the system `PATH` environment variable. However, to reflect the changes of the new `PATH`  variable, the document at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx mentions the need to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message to reflect the changes. To do this, I'm using the following piece of code:

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, NULL);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't works for me and I have to either log off / restart or manually go to Control Panel > Edit environment variables for changes to automaically applied system-wide.

My original `PATH` variable before the chage is :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

and after the change is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\hcX-af\;
```

Comment: What does SendMessageTimeout return?

Comment: Programs don't have to listen for the message even if they rely on the PATH variable. A logoff is the only reliable way to make sure that all session-based programs use an updated environment setting, on an individual process basis you can simply terminate the program and restart but that only applies to the one program.